# RecyclerViewAdapter. Ошибки при перегрузке методов

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, recyclerview

Решил я поковыряться в RecyclerView, вроде все хорошо, но почему то при перегрузке метода onBindViewHolder(), ide ругается на параметр myViewHolder holder, хочет чтобы я использовал RecyclerView.ViewHolder. При этом при перегрузке метода  onCreateViewHolder() никаких проблем нет.

Вот сам код:

```
public class RegionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

    public List<Region> regions;

    public RegionAdapter(List<Region> regions){
        this.regions = regions;
    }


    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private TextView name;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cityRecyclerViewItemName);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.region_recyclerview_item, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position){
        holder.name.setText(regions.get(position).getName());
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return regions.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: вы объявляете класс class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder, но метод public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder вынесен из него, наверное поэтому студия и пытается применить к нему RecyclerView.ViewHolder. попробуйте внести метод в тело класса.

Comment: метод onСreateViewHolder принадлежит RecyclerView.Adapter поэтому я перегружаю его в RegionAdapter, да и с ним проблем нет:)
Ошибка в onBindViewHolder, почему-то хочет чтобы я передавал ему RecyclerView.ViewHolder, а не свою версию ViewHolder'a.
Делал по этому примеру https://habrahabr.ru/post/237101/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неверно воспроизвели пример из статьи с [хабра](https://habrahabr.ru/post/237101/). При описании класса-адаптера вы должны указать тип холдера адаптера. По умолчанию (и у вас) - это `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`. А надо (и в статье так): `YoursAdapterClassName<YoursAdapterClassName.YoursHolderClassName>` - т.е. указать не дефолтный, но ваш кастомный тип холдера. Т.е. у вас должно получится

```
public class RegionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RegionAdapter.MyViewHolder>
```

Сама же ваша нынешняя ошибка вызвана тем, что при переопределении методов супер-класса можно заменить тип возвращаемого значения под-классом, но вот с параметрами метода так сделать нельзя - это одно из ограничений языка/ООП.